# Return lowest 5 values and IDs for every variable in large df in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, lapply, sapply

I have a large dataframe (4631 rows x 2995 cols). The rows represent the zip codes of all the hospitals in the US and the columns represent the zip codes of  patients. I have calculated the distance between the patient's home zips and the hospitals so that each cell value is a numeric value representing the miles between each patient's home and each hospital.

An example df is:

```
        10960     11040    56277    55379     

37160   674.14    238.04   25.89     5.31

37091   162.62    71.25    428.56    672.11

89148   931.31    0.03     389.25    1000.05

91776   15.05     508.74   315.61    101.01
```

What I want to do now is extract the lowest five values for each patient, which would represent the five closest hospitals for each patient. But not only do I need to extract the cell values but I also need the row names so I can know which zip codes those hospitals are in.

So for example, if I was only looking for the lowest two values for each patient/column, I would like to know that for patient 10960 the closest hospital is 15.05 miles away and is in the 91776 zip code, and the second closest hospital is 162.62 miles away and is in the 37091 zip code.

I have this data transposed so if it would be easier to do this by swapping the rows and columns that's fine by me. I don't need the code to do that.

I've found ways to get the lowest values using functions and apply and stuff but it doesn't give me the corresponding zip codes.

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of a sample of the dataset? Maybe something like `dput(df[1:10, 1:5])`? Are the zip codes and patient codes just the rownames and colnames respectively?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what sort of example you're asking for. Yes, the hospital zip codes are the rownames and the patient codes are the colnames and the cell values are the miles between the hospitals and the patients' home zip codes. The patient zips are in another dataset and this dataframe is just the output of my distance analysis where I calculated the distance between hospital zips and patient zips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(hospital = rownames(.)) %>% 
  gather("patient", "distance", -hospital) %>% 
  group_by(patient) %>% 
  arrange(distance) %>% 
  slice(1:5) %>% 
  ungroup
```

First add a `hospital` column from the rownames, and then in the `gather` step the columns for distance are being turned into rows - each colname becomes an entry under the new `patient` column and the distances in each column become part of the `distance` column. `group_by` and `arrange` find sort the distances within each patient, and `slice` takes the first 5 rows of each. The `ungroup` isn't required but it's nice to undo the `group_by` if the grouping is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would work:

```
library(dplyr)

test <- lapply(1:length(df), function(i) {
  x <- arrange(df, names(df)[i])
  tibble(HospitalZipCode = rownames(x)[1:5], 
         Distance = x[1:5,i, drop=TRUE], 
         Order = 1:5,
         PatientID=names(df)[i])
  }) %>% bind_rows()
```

This should give you a table with 5 rows per patient. I added a column for the order of the hospitals (1 for closest, 2 for second, etc.)